# ToC with font Verdana results in misalignments

Tags: table-of-contents

When I create a document with the default font the ToC looks fine. When I change the font to Verdana the numbers are not properly aligned - the page numbers and the space between number and chapter. The result looks like:

[image: Toc]

My preamble in the document consists of

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype} % have some better layout of individual chars
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref} % for links and PDF-specifica (and Umlaute in PDF meta-data)
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % to have the automatics ligatures of TeX
\setmainfont{Verdana}  % use font 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
```

Using LuaLatex 1.0.4, on a OpenSusue. Font is installed - otherwise I wouldn't get the results. The rest of the document seems to be working without any kind of problems. i.e. in the specific chapters the space between number and text is sufficient. Its only in the ToC.

Any ideas how to get a better alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verdana is quite large and the place reserved for the page number is too small (you get an overfull hbox warning). You can change the command `\@pnumwidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype} % have some better layout of individual chars
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref} % for links and PDF-specifica (and Umlaute in PDF meta-data)
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % to have the automatics ligatures of TeX
\setmainfont{Verdana}  % use font
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em} %more place for page number
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{122}
\section{abc}
\subsection{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx... I'll try. And what about the numbers in the chapter? They don't align neither properly - or better said the space their is too small. But in the regular chapters it's OK(although quite large/wide their). I guess when they are two digits wide the problem kicks in.

Comment: Oh one the left too, sorry didn't look. article.cls has not direct macro to adjust this, you would have to redefine internal macros or use a package like titletoc (or set em to another value). Can't you use a better class like scrartcl which has options for this in-built?

Comment: Well... I don't mind that much. If the other class has better options, why not? Can I make their as well A4 page with the margins? If so, I'll switch.... How to set the options their? So, how would an overall solution look like for Verdana? I'm little bit surprised that their isn't a complete package which adjust everything at once - when using Verdana.